# g++ 4.1.2 mixed with g++ 4.6

Tags: gcc, g++, version

So, here's the thing. To develop plugins for Maya on Linux, we have to compile with GCC 4.1.2. But this compiler doesn't support any of the new C++0x features.

would it be possible to do something like this:

```
gcc-4.6 -o test.cpp.o -c test.cpp
gcc-4.1.2 -o exec_test test.cpp.o
```

I have serious doubt it would be possible, but worth asking.

If this is not possible, is there a way to achieve something similar ?

Comment: This will certainly not work as it is.  Even a simple hello-world application will fail to link correctly.

Comment: I guess there's too much differences between the two versions to be able to link properly!

Comment: If the code you develop, can manage to avoid the C++ support libraries, you might have some success compiling into assembler (`gcc -S`), than assembling the output with older gcc. It worked for 4.7->4.4, used `auto` keyword for test.

Comment: @fork0, there's no need to do that

Comment: @Oli, have you actually tried it? A simple hello world won't depend on anything not present in GCC 4.1's libstdc++ and will link fine, without even specifying the newer libstdc++ as in my asnwer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: The question originally had gcc-4.6 doing the linking rather than the compiling, and that indeed doesn't work.

Comment: @Oli, why not? Works fine for me, by design.

Comment: P.S. @widgg: "_To develop plugins for Maya on Linux, we have to compile with GCC 4.1.2_" ... why? says who?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Autodesk says it! It's the same situation for Softimage too. They know this compiler, they know how it works, they know that their code compiles on it... and for projects that big, they won't take the risk of changing the compiler (even if at some point, they should make the effort to). It means that we're stuck with it too to develop plugins. Which is a bit sad because we cannot use the new features. But, your solution might be a workaround for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ABI for those two GCC versions is compatible, the problem is that the object compiled by GCC 4.6 might depend on symbols that are only defined by the newer GCC's C++ standard library (e.g. if you use the `std::fstream` constructor taking a `std::string` your object will have a dependency on that symbol, which is only present in recent versions of GCC that support C++11.)

It will work as long as you link to the libstdc++ from GCC 4.6 (which is `libstdc++.so.6.0.16`) i.e. by linking with `-L /path/to/gcc-4.6/lib`

You must also ensure that newer version of the library is found at run-time, i.e. by telling the dynamic loader to use that library, using one of the methods listed in the [libstdc++ manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic)

For example:

```
$ cat x.cc
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s = "output";
    std::ofstream f(s);
    std::vector<int> v(3);
    int n;
    for (auto i : v)
        ++n;
    f << n << '\n';
}
$ g++-4.6 -std=c++0x x.cc -c
$ g++-4.1 x.o
x.o: In function `main':
x.cc:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ g++-4.1 x.o -L /path/to/4.6/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/4.6/lib64
$ ./a.out
$ cat output
3
```

Comment: sweet! as simple as that ? I imagine that there's some cases where it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: All your second command does is invoke the linker, `ld`, so as long as you tell the linker how to find the right libs it makes no difference whether you invoke `ld` via GCC 4.1, or via 4.6, or directly as `ld`