# Can gcc 4.1 link a library built by gcc 4.6?

Tags: linux, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [g++ 4.1.2 mixed with g++ 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528885/g-4-1-2-mixed-with-g-4-6)

I have a library built by GCC 4.6.  I want to link this library in another server with GCC 4.1.  Can I do this?  If not, what should I do?

Comment: (a) Probably, and (b) Did you try it?  What happened?  Wouldn't it be quicker just to try it?

Comment: @BЈовић: despite its title, the 'possible duplicate' is a question about C++ rather than C, and the answer for C++ is likely to be different.  If this question is for C++ rather than C, then it applies, but unadorned gcc should apply to the C compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But the same answer applies (he needs gcc 4.6 libraries). Or, am I wrong?

Comment: C doesn't need support libraries the same way C++ does.  I'd give him an 80% or better chance of it working in C; and approximately 0% chance of it working in C++.

Comment: If the library was linked against a newer version of glibc than used with the 4.1 compiler, the answer may very well be "no" due to symbol versioning checks.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly yes, this will work.  The ELF shared library format is a standard and identical between the gcc versions.

But when you say "built by gcc 4.6", my guess is that what you really mean is that it was built on a whole platform of libraries that happens to use gcc 4.6, and you're trying to run the library on a whole system that uses 4.1.  There are going to be other library changes between these systems, and in general there is no promise of forward compatibility in Linux libraries.  Building something on say Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to run it on Fedora 13 is likely  to fail.